# Extract a string inside a div which holds many other divs with their own strings using Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

I need help to extract a comment inside a div that holds many other child divs which have there own strings.
I have this code to get all the strings inside the div.

```
try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpathCommentPage)))
        
    comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(realtiveXpathToReportComments) #list all Webelements with comments with type Report
        comment = comments[0].get_attribute("innerText")
        print(comment) 
    ## Gets this string: 
    ## "Weekly Report. This line is a title and it can vary.
    ## 10 May 2021. This line is a date and it can vary. 
    ## This is the comment I want to extract. The comment could be long. 
    ## This is a optional comment at the end. I don't want this"
        
except:
        print("could not find comments on comment page")
```

The html for the Webelement  for comment looks like this (see below). The wanted comment is inside the outer div tag, as you can see, which holds all the other unnecessery text strings as well.

```
<div data-testid="comment" type="report" class="sc-cTmXAz cwRvCX">
    <div class="sc-bCwfaz sc-QfGIp gDveND hNwnuN">
        <div class="sc-hepHJq gyIWHj">
            <svg width="28" height="27" viewBox="0 0 28 27" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-testid="report">
                <g transform="translate(.5)" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <rect fill="#E3DFF2" width="27" height="27" rx="10.916"></rect>
                    <path d="M16.009 10.89h-.602a2.73 2.73 0 00-2.723 2.916c.077 1.119.132 1.821.167 2.107.039.327.169 1.096.389 2.31a2.205 2.205 0 002.452 1.792 2.713 2.713 0 002.341-2.328c.128-.951.215-1.543.259-1.774.037-.194.162-.754.376-1.68a2.73 2.73 0 00-2.66-3.343zm6.038 4.327l-.343-.1a1.662 1.662 0 00-2.129 1.598c.001.322.003.52.007.595.005.106.037.398.093.877a1.36 1.36 0 001.515 1.192c.828-.1 1.53-.655 1.82-1.437l.172-.465a1.73 1.73 0 00-1.135-2.26zM7.453 6.436l-.565.057a3.411 3.411 0 00-3.038 3.842c.345 2.597.606 4.268.785 5.014.19.79.641 2.285 1.353 4.485a3.063 3.063 0 003.13 2.112 2.29 2.29 0 002.114-2.53c-.265-2.443-.409-4.119-.432-5.028-.02-.767.072-2.217.276-4.35a3.305 3.305 0 00-3.623-3.602z" fill="#8F7FCE"></path>
                </g>
            </svg>
            <div data-testid="activity-title" class="sc-dmiYbj bEyWbu"><span class="sc-jVBfSZ keEVDi">Weekly Report. This line is a title and it can vary.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sc-bCwfaz sc-jomqko hGiREx gbkTPQ">
            <div class="sc-bXXDC jSxSkF">10 May 2021. This line is a date and it can vary. </div>
        </div>
    </div>This is the comment I want to extract. The comment could be long or short. 
    <div data-testid="comment-reply-text" class="sc-ckXLN jnxISp">This is a optional comment at the end. I don't want this</div>
    <div class="sc-iArHnM eEOXNH">
        <form data-testid="reply-form">
            <div class="sc-jfkLlK fHByXR">
                <textarea data-testid="text-area" placeholder="Vänligen skriv ditt svar här" name="replyMessage" id="replyMessage" rows="3" height="auto" class="sc-fcmMJX ldYVmw"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="sc-bHCRaJ gPCKhJ">
                <button data-testid="comment-reply-cancel-button" type="button" class="sc-ckTSus sc-fzJAIQ kiNKGC irzfTA">Avbryt</button>
                <button data-testid="comment-reply-submit-button" type="submit" class="sc-lbVvki hxgvIg">Skicka</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can we extract the wanted comment? Can we use regular expression somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
textValue = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@data-testid='comment']").text.split("\n")[2]
print(textValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you ommited the paths it is hard to tell exactly where the problem is, but I guess you can try the answer by @itronic1990 or the snippet below.

```
wanted_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sc-cTmXAz cwRvCX').text
print(wanted_text)
```

Comment: `sc-cTmXAz cwRvCX` this will change for every execution.. looks dynamic

Comment: I agree, but it is unclear what exactly the OP wants.